# How do I structure Jobs in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

I have been tasked with setting up automated deployment and, after some research, settled on Jenkins to get the job done.  Prior to this I had approximately zero knowledge of Jenkins, beyond hearing the name.  I have no real knowledge of Devops beyond what I have learnt in the last couple of weeks; no formal training, no actual books, just Google searches.

We are not running a full blown/classic CI/CD process; this is a business decision.  The basic requirements are:

- Source code will be stored in GitHub.
- Pull requests must be peer approved.
- Pull requests must pass build/unit/db deploy tests.
- Commits to specific branches must trigger a deployment to a related specific environment (Production, Staging or Development).

The basic functionality that I am attempting to support covers (what I currently see as) two separate processes:

- On creation of a pull request, application is built, unit tests run, and db deploy tested.  Status info must be passed to GitHub.
- On commit to one of three specific branches (master, staging and dev) the application should be built, and deployed to one of three environments (production, staging and dev).

I have managed to cobble together a pipeline that does the first task rather well.  I am using the generic web hook trigger, and manually handling all steps using a declarative pipeline stored in source control.  This works rather well so far and, after much hacking, I am quite happy with the shape of it.

I am now starting work on the next bit, automated deployment.

On to my actual question(s).

In short, how do I split this up into Jobs in Jenkins?

To my mind, there are 1, 2 or 4 Jobs to be created:

- One Job to Rule them All

This seems sub-optimal to me, as the pipeline will include relatively complex conditional logic and, depending on whether the Job is triggered by a Pull Request or a Commit, different stages will be run.  The historical data will be so polluted as to be near useless.

OR

- One job for handling pull requests
- One job for handling commits

Historical data for deployments across all environments will be intermixed.  I am a little concerned that I will end up with >1 Jenkinsfile in my repository.  Although I see no technical reason why I can't have >1 Jenkinsfile, every example I see uses a single file.  Is it OK to have >1 Jenkinsfile (Jenkinsfile_Test & Jenkinsfile_Deploy) in the repository?

OR

- One job for handling pull requests
- One job for handling commits to Development
- One job for handling commits to Staging
- One job for handling commits to Production

This seems to have some benefit over the previous option, because historical data for deployments into each environment will not be cross polluting each other.  But now we're well over the >1 Jenkinsfile (perceived) limit, and I will end up with (Jenkinsfile_Test, Jenkinsfile_Deploy_Development, Jenkinsfile_Deploy_Staging and Jenkinsfile_Deploy_Production).  This method also brings either extra complexity (common code in a shared library) or copy/paste code reuse, which I certainly want to avoid.

My primary objective is for this to be maintainable by someone other than myself, because Bus Factor.  A real Devops/Jenkins person will have to update/manage all of this one day, and I would strongly prefer them not to suffer from my ignorance.

I have done countless searches, but I haven't found anything that provides the direction I need here.  Searches for best practices make no mention on handling >1 Jenkinsfile, instead focusing on the contents of a single pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

After further research, I have found *an* answer to my core question.  This might not be the absolute correct answer, but it makes sense to me, and serves my needs.

While it is technically possible to have >1 Jenkinsfile in a project, that does not appear to align with best practices.

The best practice appears to be to create a separate repository for each Jenkinsfile, which maps 1:1 with a Job in Jenkins.

To support my specific use case I have removed the Jenkinsfile from my main source code repository.  I then create 4 new repositories:

> *Project*_Jenkinsfile_Test
>   *Project*_Jenkinsfile_Deploy_Development
>   *Project*_Jenkinsfile_Deploy_Staging
>   *Project*_Jenkinsfile_Deploy_Production

Each repository contains a single Jenkinsfile and a readme.md that, in theory, contains useful information.

This separation gives me a nice view of the historical success/failure of the Test runs as a whole, and Deployments to each environment separately.

It is highly likely that I will later create a fifth repository:

> *Project*_Jenkinsfile_Deploy_SharedLibrary

This last repository would contain pipeline code that is shared amongst the four 'core' pipelines.  Once I have the 'core' pipelines up and running properly, I will consider refactoring what I can into this shared library.

I will not accept my own answer at this point, in the hope that more answers are forthcoming.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proposal I would try for your requirements based on the experience at my last job.

- Job1: builds and runs unit tests on every commit on master or whatever your main dev branch is (checks every 20 minutes or whatever suits you); this job usually finds compile and unit test issues very fast
- Job2 (optional): run integration tests and various static code checks (e.g. clang-tidy, valgrind, cppcheck, etc.) every night, if the last run of Job1 was successful; this job finds usually lots of things, but probably takes lots of time, so let it run only at night
- Job3: builds and tests every pull request for release branches; so you get some info in your pull requests, if its mature enough to be merged into the release branches
- Job4: deploys to the appropriate environment on every commit on a release branch; on dev and staging you could probably trigger some more tests, if you have them

So Job1, Job2 and Job3 should run all the time. If pull requests to your release branches are approved by QA (i.e. reviews OK and tests successful) and merged to release branches, the deployment is done by Job4 automatically.

It depends on your requirements and your dev process, if you want to trigger Job4 only manually instead.